# Restrict flyout to current AppWindow's boundary

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, submenu, bounds, flyout

I want to restrict a flyout and its submbmenu flyouts to the window of the app. This is what it looks like right now:

[image: ShouldConstrainToRootBounds is false]
 But when I try to set `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds` to `true` the submenuflyout displays really small number of items:

[image: ShouldConstrainToRootBounds is true]

How do I make my submenuflyouts display maximum number of contents while still restricting it to app's window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new feature in 1903 and above systems, that is, controls inherited from `FlyoutBase` are not constrained by app window.

I reproduced your problem, which only appears if the currently displayed sub-item is greater than the height of the current window. The specific display position is calculated internally by `MenuFlyout`, and because Flyout and Window are not at the same level, the current solution is to set `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds` to `False`, so that MenuFlyout can be completely displayed.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds` displays only 2 or 3 items while I want the flyout display maximum number of items that can fit the app's window.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, the current position property setting is invalid for excessive `MenuFlyoutSubItem`, so you may consider setting `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds` to `False` to display the menu list. I will also report it through internal channels.